# Automatically add tracker url to any public torrents from any site while downloading

Tags: download, bittorrent, isp

I've noticed an amazing thing today that I've never seen or heard before.

Within my friend's ISP, any public torrent he downloads from any site no matter what (even if the site is hosted within his local network) an announce URL of his ISP automatically gets added to the torrent client.

I don't understand how it's even possible! Does his ISP monitor, filter and modify every torrent their subscribers download?

note: the ISP's announce url doesn't add if the downloaded torrent is private.

Comment: Are you using the same client.  This isn't an ISP feature I can guarantee you that

Comment: Any bittorrent client. I don't know if it's an ISP feature or not, but I want to understand the process coz it's been eating my head.
Shall I make a video and post it here as proof? It may also help you to guess the technology behind this.

Comment: @lmtiaz - Why don't you contact your friends  ISP and ask?  I might have not understood the original question.

Comment: Thank you, @Ramhound. I'll try to contact them. But I guess the chance is too low. My friend lives in India and me on Bangladesh.
Also I don't think the'll reveal their secrets. Thank you again. I'll post here if I get to know anything about it.